# Process-level parallelism in Scala

Tags: scala, concurrency, akka

I'd like to use reflection in combination with parallel processing in Scala, but I'm getting bitten by [reflection's lack of thread safety](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/thread-safety.html).
So, I'm considering just running each task in its own process (not thread).
Is there any easy way to do this?

For example, is there a way to configure `.par` so it spawns processes, not threads? Or is there some function `fork` that takes a closure and runs it in a new process?

EDIT: Futures are apparently a good way to go.
However, I still need to figure out how to run them in separate *processes*.

EDIT 2: I'm still having concurrency issues, even when using Akka's "fork-join-executor" dispatcher, which sure sounds like it should be forking processes. However, when I run `ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName()` inside the Futures, it seems everything still lives in the same process.
Is this the right way to check for actual process-level parallelism?
Am I using the correct Akka dispatcher?

EDIT 3: I realize reflection sucks. Unfortunately it is used in a library I need.

Comment: It sounds like most of the problems associated with lack of thread safety for reflection might be solvable by using a separate Class Loader on each thread. Does anyone else have thoughts on that?

Comment: If you're a newcomer to Scala, you almost certainly should *not* be looking to reflection to solve programming or design problems. A very strong principle of Scala programming and design is *static* typing. You should know "up front" (when you write the code) what types your program traffics in. So-called "dynamic typing" is a kind of mealy-mouthed, "you know what I mean, compiler, right?" programming that is ultimately counter-productive, at least in large systems. Avoid it!

Comment: could post post a sample code demonstrating the issue?

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked into Scala [Actors](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.actors.Actor) or [Akka](http://akka.io/)? There may be no more compelling reason to use Scala than for parallel and asynchronous programming. It's baked into the language. Check out these facilities. I'm pretty sure you'll find what you need.

Comment: Um, no, but now that you mention it, I totally should have. But I've never used it, directly. Any pointers for this simple use case?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough about what you're trying to do to help. I can say though that Akka is probably overkill. Actors should be sufficient. This should help if you can get past the monotonous delivery: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bNLeo36pFls

Comment: It looks like Akka Futures will do the trick, so long as they're configured to run in their own processes: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/scala/futures.html

Answer (score 0):

There's little information as regards the problem you're trying to solve here...previous answers are pretty much on the ball - look at Actors etc...Akka and you may find that you don't need to necessarily do anything too complicated.  Introspection/reflection in a multi-threaded environment usually means a messy and not well thought-out strategy in terms of decomposing the problem in hand.

Comment: Unfortunately, reflection is unavoidable as it's baked into (the extremely useful) scala-pickling at the moment.

Comment: So is it a problem around serialisation and complexity thereof?